# How do I make model.generate() use more than 2 cpu cores? (huggingface transformers LlamaForCausalLM)

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm using code that looks like this

```
import torch
from transformers import LlamaTokenizer, LlamaForCausalLM
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("/path/to/model")
model = LlamaForCausalLM.from_pretrained("/path/to/model")
prompt="prompt text"
inputs = tokenizer(prompt, return_tensors="pt")
generate_ids = model.generate(inputs.input_ids, max_length=1500, temperature=0.7, do_sample=True)
tokenizer.batch_decode(generate_ids, skip_special_tokens=True, clean_up_tokenization_spaces=False)[0]
```

I expect it to use 100% cpu until its done generating but it only uses 2 of 12 cores.
When I try searching for solutions all I can find are people trying to prevent model.generate() from using 100% cpu.